# get a new value input .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some problem understanding how to get a new value from my **span id='savings'**. As you can see I need to make my bank account works. if a deposit is all good, but when I want to withdraw some money it starts from my starting point of 0, instead of starting from what I deposited.

```js
var inputAmount = document.getElementById('inputAmount');
var withdBtn = document.getElementById('withdBtn');
var savingSpan = document.querySelector('#savings');
var myBalance = Number(savingSpan.innerHTML);
var depBtn = document.getElementById('depBtn');

depBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var savAmount = Number(inputAmount.value);
  var depositBalance = savAmount + myBalance;
  savingSpan.innerHTML = depositBalance;
});

withdBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var savAmount = Number(inputAmount.value);
  var withdrawBalance = (myBalance.innerHTML) - savAmount;
  savingSpan.innerHTML = withdrawBalance;

});
```

```html
<h1></h1>

<div class="savings" id="accounts">

  <h2>Savings Account</h2>

  <h3> Your current balance is </h3>
  <span>$</span>  <span id="savings">  00.00 </span>

  <p>
    <input id="inputAmount" type="number" placeholder="Enter amount here">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button id="withdBtn" type="button">Withdraw</button>
    <button id="depBtn" type="button">Deposit</button>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `querySelector('#savings')` rather than `getElementById('savings')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch `myBalance` with `savingSpan`  in the `withBtn` function. `myBalance` is a number and therefore doesn't have the attribut `innerHTML`

```
withdBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var savAmount = Number(inputAmount.value);
    var withdrawBalance = (savingSpan.innerHTML) - savAmount;
    savingSpan.innerHTML = withdrawBalance;
});
```

EDIT:
For multiple deposits, you also need to replace `myBalance` with `Number(savingSpan.innerHTML)` in the `depBtn` function. `myBalance` only gets sets once at the beginning and therefore doesn't represent the current balance.

```
depBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var savAmount = Number(inputAmount.value);
    var depositBalance = savAmount + Number(savingSpan.innerHTML);
    savingSpan.innerHTML = depositBalance;
});
```

Comment: so simple...how didn't I get it? THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. You're calling myBalance.innerHTML, but it should just be myBalance as this variable is already holding the value.
2. You need to update you myBalance variable when the buttons are clicked. Currently the

Simple solution: Just replace depositBalance and withdrawBalance with myBalance.

```
depBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var savAmount = Number(inputAmount.value);
    myBalance = savAmount + myBalance;
    savingSpan.innerHTML = myBalance; 
});


withdBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var savAmount = Number(inputAmount.value);
    myBalance = myBalance - savAmount;

   savingSpan.innerHTML = myBalance;
});
```

See also https://jsfiddle.net/enpo/wdu87Lek/.